# remove duplicates (tuple of tuples)

Tags: python, python-3.x, duplicates, tuples

input data:

```
input_tuple = (
            (1, 'name1', 'Noah'),
            (1, 'name2', 'Liam'),

            (2, 'name3', 'Mason'),

            (3, 'name4', 'Mason'),

            (4, 'name5', 'Noah'),
            (4, 'name6', 'Liam'),

            (5, 'name7', 'Elijah'),
            (5, 'name8', 'Noah'),
            (5, 'name9', 'Liam')
          )
```

converted into dict(key, value):

```
input_tuple = {
         1: [['name1', 'Noah'], ['name2', 'Liam']],
         2: [['name3', 'Mason']],
         3: [['name4', 'Mason']],
         4: [['name5', 'Noah'], ['name6', 'Liam']],
         5: [['name7', 'Elijah'], ['name8', 'Noah'], 
             ['name9', 'Liam']]
         }
```

did some more filter just for understanding the data model:

```
    dict =   
    {
    1: ['Noah', 'Liam'],
    2: ['Mason'],
    3: ['Mason'],
    4: ['Noah', 'Liam'],
    5: ['Elijah', 'Noah', 'Liam']
    }
```

Now i want to eliminate duplicate and then revert back to tuple like below:
duplicate matching conditions:
1) eliminate duplicate if len(value) > 1
2) value should exact match not partial.

Note:
key 2 and 3 value is not duplicate because len(value) is not -gt 1
key 4 value has gone because its exact duplicate
since we are doing exact matching, hence in key 5 value ['Noah', Liam] will not go.

```
 output_tuple = 
      (
        (1, 'name1', 'Noah'),
        (1, 'name2', 'Liam'),

        (2, 'name3', 'Mason'),

        (3, 'name4', 'Mason'),

        (5, 'name7', 'Elijah'),
        (5, 'name8', 'Noah'),
        (5, 'name9', 'Liam')
      )
```

code which i tried:

```
from functools import reduce
from collections import defaultdict

input_tuple_dictionary = defaultdict(list)
for (key, *value) in input_tuple:
    input_tuple_dictionary[key].append(value[1])

input_tuple_dictionary
for index in range(len(input_tuple_dictionary)-1):
    for key, value in input_tuple_dictionary.items():
        if len(value) > 1:
            if value == value[index+1]:
                print(key)
```

Comment: How exactly is a "duplicate" defined?

Comment: Why are Noah and Liam for id = 5 not removed?

Comment: because if you compare with 1: and 5 key value. its not exactly same.

Comment: "['Elijah', 'Noah', 'Liam']" is not equal to "['Noah', 'Liam']"

Comment: So why are Noah and Liam removed for id = 4?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
You haven't defined *duplicate*, haven't drawn a clear distinction between actual and desired output, and included superfluous code, so we have trouble helping.

Comment: It makes sense to me that `dict[1]` and `dict[4]` are equal to one another, so one should be removed. But `dict[2]` and `dict[3]` are equal, so how come both appear in the output tuple?

Comment: because: 1:"['Noah', 'Liam']" == 4:"['Noah', 'Liam']" is True

Comment: yes 2 and 3 are equal, but here we need to only check those duplicate which len(value) > 1

Comment: Hi Prune, i updated the main page. please let me know if i have to explain more. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution using a `defaultdict` of `set` objects and `toolz.unique`. `toolz.unique` is equivalent to the `itertools` [`unique_everseen` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) available in the docs.

The idea is to find keys with lone values and also keys which do not have duplicate values. The *union* of these two categories make up your result.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from toolz import unique

dd = defaultdict(set)

for k, _, v in input_tuple:
    dd[k].add(v)

lones = {k for k, v in dd.items() if len(v) == 1}
uniques = set(unique(dd, key=lambda x: frozenset(dd[x])))

res = tuple(i for i in input_tuple if i[0] in lones | uniques)
```

Result:

```
print(res)

((1, 'name1', 'Noah'),
 (1, 'name2', 'Liam'),
 (2, 'name3', 'Mason'),
 (3, 'name4', 'Mason'),
 (5, 'name7', 'Elijah'),
 (5, 'name8', 'Noah'),
 (5, 'name9', 'Liam'))
```

Comment: getting module error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'toolz'

Comment: @Vikash, See the 2nd sentence .. `toolz.unique is equivalent to the itertools unique_everseen recipe available in the docs.` I've added a link for you.

Comment: Hi All, Thank You so much for your wonderful responses and support. my data are little huge and there is memory overflow.. so I will run tomorrow with full set and then tick the answer.

Comment: However , meanwhile if possible can you please assist me to create comprehension code like below:

Comment: # chooses first seen as unique (this is for single duplicate check)
result = (tuple({(x[0], x[4]): x for x in input_tuple[::-1]}.values())[::-1])

Comment: @Vikash, The problem with your dictionary comprehension is order matters, i.e. `('A', 'B')` not the same as `('B', 'A')`. That's why I use `frozenset`.

Comment: @Vikash did you ran our answer with complete data-set ?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Using the dict format of yours
data = [set(dict[x]) for x in range(1, len(dict) + 1)]
input_tuple = dict
seen = []
output_tuple = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    if (data[i] not in seen) or len(data[i]) == 1:
        for j in range(len(input_data)):
            if input_data[j][0] == i + 1:
                output_tuple.append(input_data[j])
    seen.append(data[i])
output_tuple = tuple(output_tuple)
```

If you did not understand please ask

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

One common solution for skipping duplicates is to keep a set that contains all of the elements you've already seen. If the object has been seen before, you don't add it to the result.

The tricky bit is that the object you're trying to un-duplicate is the aggregation of multiple objects that reside within different tuples in your collection. Using `groupby` is an effective way to get those objects together in one convenient package.

```
from itertools import groupby

input_tuple = (
    (1, 'name1', 'Noah'),
    (1, 'name2', 'Liam'),

    (2, 'name3', 'Mason'),

    (3, 'name4', 'Mason'),

    (4, 'name5', 'Noah'),
    (4, 'name6', 'Liam'),

    (5, 'name7', 'Elijah'),
    (5, 'name8', 'Noah'),
    (5, 'name9', 'Liam')
  )

seen = set()
result = []
for _, group in groupby(input_tuple, key=lambda t: t[0]):
    #convert from iterator to list, since we want to iterate this more than once
    group = list(group)
    #extract just the names from each tuple.
    names = tuple(t[2] for t in group)
    #check for duplicates, but only for name groups with more than one element.
    if len(names) == 1 or names not in seen:
        result.extend(group)
    seen.add(names)

print(result)
```

Result:

```
[(1, 'name1', 'Noah'), (1, 'name2', 'Liam'), (2, 'name3', 'Mason'), (3, 'name4', 'Mason'), (5, 'name7', 'Elijah'), (5, 'name8', 'Noah'), (5, 'name9', 'Liam')]
```

Comment: nice answer, but if (4, 'name6', 'Liam') comes before (4, 'name5', 'Noah') it doesn't produce correct result.

Comment: You're right. If, for the purposes of duplicate detection, you wanted to completely disregard the order of names within a group, you could do `names = tuple(sorted(t[2] for t in group))`. If you _do_ care about the order of names within a group, but want to order lexicographically by the `"name<digit>"` element, then perhaps you could do `names = tuple(t[2] for t in sorted(group, key=lambda t: t[1]))`.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. This will help OP to decide what kind of behavior he wants, originally I also didn't take into account the problem that I found in your solution but for mine it was quick fix, I just sort the list( names list which has same id) before creating hash from it( via tuple).

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

dct = defaultdict(list) 

for k,n_id,name in input_tuple:
    dct[k].append(name)

#print(dct)

seen = set()
ignore_id_set = set()

for _id, _namelst in dct.items():
    if len(_namelst) > 1:
        k = tuple(sorted(_namelst)) # note 1 

        if k not in seen:
            seen.add(k)
        else:
            ignore_id_set.add(_id) # duplicate

#print(seen)

# del dct,seen # dct,seen are now eligible for garbage collection

output = tuple(item for item in input_tuple if item[0] not in ignore_id_set)
print(output)


'''
note 1:
    important to sort **if** situations like this can be possible
     (1, 'name1', 'Noah'),
     (1, 'name2', 'Liam'),

     (4, 'name6', 'Liam'),
     (4, 'name5', 'Noah'),

     because when we will create dct it will result in 

     1 : [Noah,Liam]
     4 : [Liam,Noah]

     since we want to treat them as duplicates we need to sort before creating their hash( via tuple)

**else** no need to do sort

'''
```

Comment: Hi Tanmay, its working fine, but  since i have to process a huge data, hence it may create memory issue.